# xslfo, xsl, pdf, html: Reset the footer page number for dynamically generated pdf document after some pages

Tags: html, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

```
<!--Page Footer-->
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
<xsl:apply-templates select="footer" />
<fo:block text-align="right">

Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="document-end" />
Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="document-end-div" /> 

</fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

The above code is placed inside an xslt file which is being used in an htm file. The htm file is used to generate a pdf which can have dynamic number of pages.

There are two sections in which the pdf is divided, 'document-end' in the code above signifies end of one of the 'section' which is of type 'section' and 'document-end-div' in the code above signifies another section which is of type 'div'.

```
When section 1 which is a div has 2 pages and section 2 which is a section has 4 pages then footer has the output as of now like:
For the 1st Page Footer: Page 1 of 2, Page 1 of 6
For the 2nd Page Footer: Page 2 of 2, Page 2 of 6
For the 3rd Page Footer: Page 3 of 2, Page 3 of 6
For the 4th Page Footer: Page 4 of 2, Page 4 of 6.....

Can you please help us to get the footer output as:
For the 1st Page Footer: Page 1 of 2
For the 2nd Page Footer: Page 2 of 2
For the 3rd Page Footer: Page 1 of 4
For the 4th Page Footer: Page 2 of 4
For the 4th Page Footer: Page 3 of 4
For the 4th Page Footer: Page 4 of 4.....
```

Note: The Pdf page numbers are dynamic and the number of pages that belong to the two sections are also dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the fo:page-number at the start of a page-sequence, so it looks like you have to modify your template to start a new page-sequence for each section.

By the way, navigation in a PDF where the page numbering is restarted is difficult. In your table of contents, for instance:

- if the TOC entry reads 'Installation...page 226' it's instantly clear where the reader has to go (especially when you print the PDF)
- if the TOC entry reads 'Installation...page 14-1' you have to leaf through the pages to find section 14, with no indication of where it might be.

You can still put a section indicator in the footer of the document, it's easy enough to put e.g. the section number and title in the footer (using markers to read the title information).